# Laravel 'auth' middleware sets wrong 'url.intended' session data when running behind reverse proxy

Tags: php, laravel, reverse-proxy

**Background:**

I'm developing a Laravel 5.8 application running inside a Docker container on a server behind a reverse proxy, forwarding requests to the application based on a URL subdirectory, e.g. `example.org/laravel/`.

Everything (Routes, HTTPS links, assets, ...) is working fine, except the redirect to the intended page after login.

I've accomplished proper URL generation for routes, assets, etc. by using

```
app('url')->forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));  // https://example.org/laravel/
app('url')->forceScheme('https');
```

**My Problem:**

Suppose I have defined a route `/foo` with the `auth` middleware. When I'm logged out and visit `example.org/laravel/foo` I am correctly redirected to `example.org/laravel/login`, but after login I'm redirected to `example.org/foo`, which does not exist.

**Investigation results:**

Accessing `/foo` while being logged out

1. `auth` middleware throws an `AuthenticatedException`, which is caught in `Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline` and passed to `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated()` (via `Handler::render()`)
2. `Handler::unauthenticated()` returns `redirect()->guest()` (`Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::guest()`)
3. `Redirector::guest()` sets the `url.intended` session key to `$this->generator->full()` (`Illuminate\Http\Request::fullUrl()` via `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::full()`)
4. `Request::fullUrl()` calls `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getUri()` (via `$this->url()`)
5. `Request::getUri()` builds the URL from the `$_SERVER` and request header data (see below) as follows (`$qs`: query string):

```
$this->getScheme().'://'.$this->getHttpHost().$this->getBaseUrl().$this->getPathInfo().$qs
---
getScheme()   => 'http'         // As $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is not set
getHttpHost() => 'example.org'  // From $this->headers->get('HOST')
getBaseUrl()  => ''             // From $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']   *[1]
getPathInfo() => '//foo'        // From $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$qs           => ''             // From $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
---
*[1]: In Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::prepareBaseUrl():
      $baseUrl    = 'index.php' (L. 1745)
      $requestUri = '//foo'     (L. 1768)
      $prefix     = '/'         (L. 1778)
   => return ''                 (L. 1780)
```

6. This results in session `url.intended` being set to `http://example.org//foo` instead of `http(s)://example.org/laravel/foo`

---

**`$_SERVER` data (excerpt):**

```
"HTTP_HOST" => "example.org"
"SERVER_NAME" => "example.org"
"QUERY_STRING" => ""
"REQUEST_URI" => "//foo"
"SCRIPT_NAME" => "/index.php"
```

**Exact Composer package versions:**

- laravel/framework: v5.8.3
- symfony/http-foundation: v4.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I researched little bit and find that problem is at `$_SERVER` variable.

It sets wrong value on `HTTP_POST` when proxying some domain to local ip as below:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
  }
}
```

I fixed it by manually setting `HTTP_HOST` on proxy.

In your situation you need to add this line: `proxy_set_header Host example.org/laravel;`

My situation is different than yours little bit. It redirects me to `http://127.0.0.1:4567` after successfully login on `domain.com`. Because Laravel's `session.url_previous` was wrong. Which comes from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

As a result I hope this will help you.

Whole Nginx conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name domain.com;

  location / {
    #changes happened here
    proxy_set_header Host domain.com;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
  }
}
```